# Python: Predicting series of numbers without INPUT to a NN

Tags: python, neural-network, statistics, series, prediction

I have a random list of series (integers) along with dates in a csv like:

```
1/1/2019,34 44 57 62 70

12/28/2018,09 10 25 37 38

12/25/2018,02 08 42 43 50

12/21/2018,10 13 61 62 70

12/18/2018,13 22 32 60 69

12/14/2018,05 22 26 43 49

12/11/2018,04 38 39 54 59

12/7/2018,04 10 20 33 57

12/4/2018,28 31 41 42 50
```

The list goes all the way back to year 1997. What I am trying is to predict the next series (or as closest as possible) based on these data:

The size of the list (2336)

What have I tried?

The approach that I've used so far is (e.g. for `1/1/2019,34 44 57 62 70`):

1) Get the occurrence of each number in the list, i.e. the number `34` has occurred `170` times out the total list (2336).

2) Find the percentage of each number that has occurred. i.e.

```
Perc/Chances(34) = Occurrence/TotalNo.

Chances(34) = 170/2336
Chances(34) = 0.072 ~ 07
```

One way to get the list would be to just find the 5 numbers from the list with the least Percentages. but that won't be much effective.

On the other hand, Now I have a data which has each number, its percentage and its occurrence. Is there any way I can somehow train a neural network that predicts the next series? or closest.

Hierarchy:

[image: t1]

Where comp_data.csv contains data like:

```
1/1/2019,34 44 57 62 70

12/28/2018,09 10 25 37 38

12/25/2018,02 08 42 43 50

12/21/2018,10 13 61 62 70

12/18/2018,13 22 32 60 69

12/14/2018,05 22 26 43 49

12/11/2018,04 38 39 54 59

12/7/2018,04 10 20 33 57

12/4/2018,28 31 41 42 50
```

and occurrence.csv contains:

```
34,170

44,197

57,36

62,38

70,37

09,186

10,210

25,197

37,185

38,206

02,217

08,185
```

and report.csv contains the number, occurrence and its percentage:

```
34,3,11

44,1,03

57,5,19

62,5,19

70,5,19

09,1,03

10,5,19

25,2,07

37,3,11

38,2,07

02,1,03

08,2,07
```

So I have the list of series, its occurrences over a period of time, and the percentages. Is there anyway I can create a NN that expects some INPUTS trains over a data and predicts the OUT (a series in this case)

**The Problem:**

Which ones would be the Input? As it is a pure random problem. PS. I cannot provide any Input since I need a series without INPUT. Perhaps, a LSTM Network for Regression?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I appreciate your response, but I have stated the approach that I used but cannot understand how to use that set of data in neural network so I don't have to use a mathematical formula everytime.

Comment: @PatrickArtner It is python, I will add some snippets to have it more crystal. Thank you. PS. I know how to create a NN just not the way to manipulate this data in a manner that could be used in some NN.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Just did :)

Comment: It seems like you are trying to win the toss guessing heads because it went tails the last times.

Comment: Still doubt this will get you an answer - SO loves condensed, short, specific questions -  your shows lots of things, no code ... maybe someone will come by and make sense out of all this.

Comment: (f.e. I have a list of numbers and percentage of occurences - I tried to train my NN like this (insert your NN creating code using Keras or whatever as [mcve]) to predict which number will come next but I get (insert _output_) where I assumed to get (_other output_)). and remove all the different files you have. Dunno - you'll see if someone answers

Comment: @PatrickArtner no worries, let me just create a NN and provide that information as well. Thank you for your patience. I will be more concise next time. cheers

Comment: not sure how tied to NNs you are but ["gaussian processes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) are great for dealing with [time series data](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Pubs/philTransA_2012.pdf)

Comment: @SamMason do you think LSTM Network for Regression could be useful?

Comment: could be; depends on the problem and what you're actually trying to model.  convnets might be good as well.  this isn't really the forum for this sort of question though, I'd suggest reading around similar models